# Find text within li and replace with jquery

Tags: jquery

What i want to do is find a certain `<li>` which contains the words people and then replace this with people and an image?

This is the current html

```
<div class="subMenu">
        <ul>
            <li class="">
               <span>
                   <a href="/sally">People</a>
               </span>
            </li>
            <li class="">
               <span>
                   <a href="/working-us">Working with us</a>
               </span>
            </li>
            <li class="">
               <span>
                   <a href="/delegate">Delegate Resource</a>
               </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

i want to replace the text 'People' with '`People <img src="/Img/banner.png" alt="">`'

can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one finds all the `<a>` elements in `<li>` elements that contains the text `People` then inserts an image [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) it:

`$("li a:contains('People')").after('<img src="/Img/banner.png" alt="">');`

This one finds all the `<li>` elements that contains the text `People` then it inserts an image after the child `<a>` elements if there is any:

`$("li:contains('People') a").after('<img src="/Img/banner.png" alt="">');`

Answer (score 5):

Basically you want to append an image to the li which has text People. Try like below,

```
$('.subMenu li:contains(People)')
        .append('<img src="/Img/banner.png" alt="">');
```

Used [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector, which looks for the text in the li.

Comment: +1 Best answer posted, although that selector is probably a little verbose.  Maybe take out the `ul`.

Answer (score 1):

`$('*:contains("People")').html('People <img src="/Img/banner.png" alt="">');`